# How to reach to a child div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to make a 'show more' button in jQuery but having some problems.

```
<div class="text-container">
  <h1>Title goes here</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <div class="content hideContent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <p>Some more text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Some more text</li>
      <li>Some more text</li>
      <li>Some more text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="show-more">
    <a href="#">Show more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

that is the HTML. And here is the jQuery:

```
$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $content = $this.parent().prev(".content");
  var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();

  if (linkText === "SHOW MORE") {
    linkText = "Show less";
    $content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);
  } else {
    linkText = "Show more";
    $content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 400);
  };

  $this.text(linkText);
});
```

When content is only under the text container it works fine. But it doesn't work if I add a parent div, for example:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content hideContent">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
         sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
         <p>Some more text</p>
         <ul>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

How can I reach to content div when it is now a child div in jQuery? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move the content/hideContent to the wrapper div: ` <div class="wrapper content hideContent">`   As it is, you would be always showing the .wrapper which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Or just: `$this.parent().prev(".wrapper").find(".content");`

Comment: Or better: `$this.closest(".text-container").find(".content")` then you can move it around as much as you like as long as the content and button are in the same text-container

Comment: Off topic: you shouldn't need to toggle both `show` and `hide` classes.  Pick a default (eg shown) then add css `.content` to show it how you want, then add css for `.content.hideContent` to hide it - then you only need to toggle hideContent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were trying to do? Use the `parentNode` to go up the DOM and then issue a `querySelector` to find the DIV.content that you wish to show/hide.

```js
$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
  let div=this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.content');
  let classes=['showContent','hideContent'];
  
  if( div.classList.contains( classes[0] ) )div.classList.replace( classes[0],classes[1] );
  else div.classList.replace( classes[1], classes[0] );
  
  this.textContent = this.textContent=='Show more' ? 'Show less' : 'Show more';
});
```

```css
.showContent{
  display:block;
}
.hideContent{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="text-container">
  <h1>Title goes here</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <div class="content hideContent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <p>Some more text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Some more text</li>
      <li>Some more text</li>
      <li>Some more text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="show-more">
    <a href="#">Show more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `closest` and `find` pointing at the outer container

I also do a bit of refactoring

like this

```js
$(() => {
  $('.show-more a').on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const $this = $(e.target)
    const $content = $this.closest('.text-container').find('.content')

    $content.toggleClass("hideContent").toggleClass('showContent');

    const linkText = $content.hasClass('hideContent')? 'Show more':'Show less'
    $this.text(linkText);
  })

})
```

```css
.hideContent {
 display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-container">
  <h1>Title goes here</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content hideContent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <p>Some more text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Some more text</li>
      <li>Some more text</li>
      <li>Some more text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="show-more">
    <a href="#">Show more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ForEach loop which helps you to show/hide content for each post on the same page. And you don't need to use jQuery anymore.

```js
 let showMoreBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.show-more');
showMoreBtn.forEach((eachBtn)=>{
    let textContainer =  eachBtn.parentNode;
    let contentBox = textContainer.querySelector('.content').classList;
    eachBtn.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        if(contentBox.contains('hideContent')){
            contentBox.remove('hideContent');
            contentBox.add('showContent');
            eachBtn.innerHTML = ` <a href="#">Show less</a>`;
        }else{
            contentBox.add('hideContent');
            contentBox.remove('showContent');
            eachBtn.innerHTML = ` <a href="#">Show more</a>`;
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.content.hideContent{display:none;}
.content.showContent{display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <h1>Title goes here</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <div class="content hideContent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <p>Some more text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Some more text</li>
      <li>Some more text</li>
      <li>Some more text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="show-more">
    <a href="#">Show more</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text-container">
  <h1>Title goes here</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <div class="content hideContent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <p>Some more text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Some more text</li>
      <li>Some more text</li>
      <li>Some more text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="show-more">
    <a href="#">Show more</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text-container">
  <h1>Title goes here</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <div class="content hideContent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    <p>Some more text</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Some more text</li>
      <li>Some more text</li>
      <li>Some more text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="show-more">
    <a href="#">Show more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```